# How to change value from span tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is html code

```
<div style="float: left; padding-top: 8px; width: 340px; overflow: hidden;" id="about_me_text_contents">    
    <b><span class="notranslate">Name</span></b>        
    <br>
    <span style="font-size:80%">Since: <span data-sl-tgtfmt="shortDate" data-sl-dtfmt="%m/%d/%y" class="SL_date">05/17/13</span></span><br>       
    <br>
    Male
    <br>    
    Age: <span class="notranslate">23</span>
    <br>        
    United States - NY
    <br>
    Last log on: <span class="notranslate"></span>
    <br>    
    <br style="line-height:12px;">
    <i id="user_tagline"><span class="notranslate">Type your tagline here</span></i>
    <br>
    <div id="aboutme_conditional_information_div">
    <div id="aboutme_gallery_div" style="line-height:12px; padding-bottom: 8px;">
        <span style="font-size:80%"><a class="see-my-albums" href="http://www.test.com">See My Albums (1)</a>
        </span>
    </div>
    </div>  
 </div>
```

What I'm doing here like code below but this not change the Age value number but change only something else value. Maybe I can try using `<br>` count. Hurm...Idk.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('.notranslate span').html("your new string");

});//]]>  

</script>
```

I would like to use Jquery to change the span value of "Age: 23 to my number manually". I am somewhat new to Javascript and Jquery, so how would I change that span value without it having an id to reference.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: `$('.notranslate').html("your new string");` can you try if this works?

Comment: this works but it's change to all value to "your new string" which have notranslate class in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS query selectors to grab the HTML element that you want to chain. You can daisy-chain selectors together to make them more specific.

For example, `#about_me_text_contents` would select the element with the id of "about_me_text_contents", while `#about_me_text_contents span` would select one or more `span` elements inside the element that id. To take it a step further, you could grab only the second span by using this selector: `#about_me_text_contents span:nth-of-type(2)`

As an alternative, you can be less specific in your CSS selector, grabbing an entire array of elements, then reference the one you want to use.

Decent CSS selectors references:

- [Selectors W3C Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)
- [Selectors on Mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors) (unofficial)
- [CSS Selectors Reference on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) (unofficial)

CSS selectors can be used both by jQuery and by native JavaScript (using `document.querySelector()` and `document.querySelectorAll()` to select elements.

Here's a demo using your provided HTML:

```js
var ageSpan = document.querySelector("#about_me_text_contents span:nth-of-type(2)");
/* Note that you could also do the following: */
// ageSpan = document.querySelectorAll("#about_me_text_contents span.notranslate")[1];
ageSpan.innerHTML = "A billion years old!";
```

```html
<div style="float: left; padding-top: 8px; width: 340px; overflow: hidden;" id="about_me_text_contents">
  <b><span class="notranslate">Name</span></b> 
  <br>
  <span style="font-size:80%">Since: <span data-sl-tgtfmt="shortDate" data-sl-dtfmt="%m/%d/%y" class="SL_date">05/17/13</span></span>
  <br>
  <br>Male
  <br>Age: <span class="notranslate">23</span>
  <br>United States - NY
  <br>Last log on: <span class="notranslate"></span>
  <br>
  <br style="line-height:12px;">
  <i id="user_tagline"><span class="notranslate">Type your tagline here</span></i>
  <br>
  <div id="aboutme_conditional_information_div">
    <div id="aboutme_gallery_div" style="line-height:12px; padding-bottom: 8px;">
      <span style="font-size:80%"><a class="see-my-albums" href="http://www.test.com">See My Albums (1)</a>
        </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The class is in the span element you need to combine those 2 selectors also since there are multiple elements with the same class you need to get the second span

```
$('span.notranslate').eq(1).html("your new string");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gufuw8oq/1/)

---

Another solution is to add a special class to the age span and use that in the selector instead of the common `notranslate` class like

```
<span class="notranslate age">23</span>
```

then

```
$('span.age').html("your new string");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gufuw8oq/2/)

Comment: so the answer is .eq(3). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Span has class name `notranslate` hence you need to use the selector `span.notranslate`. also second span element holds the value of age. you would also need to use `.eq(1)` to target the second span. Something like this:

```
$('span.notranslate:eq(1)').html("new age here");
```